# web forms insert data into sql server table from dataset returned by soap service

Tags: .net, sql-server, dataset

I need to create web forms app that insert data into sql server 2014 database table from dataset returned by SOAP service. I use next code:

```
        DataSet ds;

        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDb"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from catalog", conn);
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand();
        insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into catalog(artId, ardDesc) values(@aid, @desc)";
        insertCommand.Connection = conn;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@aid", SqlDbType.Int);
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

        adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;

        servProxy.prodService author = new servProxy.prodService();
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate(@"D:\locCert\certName.p12", "1234");
        if (cert != null)
        {
            author.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            try
            {
                ds = author.GetProdList();

                conn.Open();
                cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle error
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // handle ...
        }
```

When I run code nothing happens, I made mistake somewhere but don't know where. When insert breakpoint can see that dataset table is successfully populated but inserting into database is without success. 
Can I insert data into only two columns, there are 15 columns in db table and so in dataset? Column names in dataset and db table are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *DataAdapter.Update* method applies the INSERT command only for the rows whose [RowState property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to *DataRowState.Added*.
Probably, your service returns a DataSet with the table's rows with state equal to *DataRowState.Unchanged*.

You have no choice, but loop over the table's rows and call, for each one, [DataRow.SetAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setadded(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
try
{
    ds = author.GetProdList();
    foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        row.SetAdded();

    conn.Open();
    cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

Consider also that the Update method executes a row by row update and this, with large sets of rows, could be very slow. In this case is preferable to build a block of inserts text all concatenated together and separated by a semicolon (batch updates) and, of course, with all the parameters required by the block.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I tried but with no success. Do I need to have the same names on DS Table and DB Table? How can I find the name of DS Table, SOAP Service is not mine and I have no control over it?

Comment: I see now. The problem was in select statement, when I put `SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [myDb].[dbo].[catalog]", conn);` it was success. So, `row.SetAdded();` solved my problem